# Web Scraping Python with Requests (Login)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website using the python `requests` module and have needed to login to the site to retrieve the data I want. I have written a script which should work but is not. I am unsure as to wether this is because of the authentication method for the login of the site. This is the website i am trying to scrape: https://ashwoodvic.compass.education/login.aspx?sessionstate=disabled

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

login_url = "https://ashwoodvic.compass.education/login.aspx?sessionstate=disabled"
target_url = "https://ashwoodvic.compass.education"

login_data = { "username": "my_username", "password": "my_password"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get(login_url)
    page_login = s.post(login_url, data = login_data)
    page = s.get(target_url)
    final_page = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    print(final_page.title)
```

This is the html of the password box:

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="metro-input" placeholder="Username" value="">
<span id="username-error" class=""></span>
<label class="ie789Only"> Password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="metro-input" placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="Sign in" id="button1" class="metro-button">
```

The script does not contain any errors but just fails to login to the website and the title returned at the end was Login. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message you receive?

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't clear on this but I don't receive an error from the python code, the script just fails to login

Comment: How do you see that it fails to log in?

Comment: That website is a school search box and a captcha checker - how do you get past that?

Comment: Sometimes you have to manually enter the school name but once you've done it once it never comes up again. As to how i see that it fails to log in, there is a line of code at the end of the script which prints of the page title. The title of the login in page is `Login | Compass`, whereas the title of the home page is `Home | Compass` (I've tested this through developer tools in chrome).